# 名前空間 net.webclient は system.net.webclient の省略形であり、同じものですか？

Tags: .net, powershell

下記２つのコマンドにおいて、`net.webclient` は `system.net.webclient` の省略形でありいずれも同じと考えてよいでしょうか。

```
powershell -c (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadfile('http://<IP>:<Port>/<File Name>','C:\<Path>\to\<File Name>')
```

```
powershell -c (new-object net.webclient).downloadfile('http://<IP>:<Port>/<File Name>','C:\<Path>\to\<File Name>')
```

Answer (score 1):

はい、PowerShellにおいて、名前空間`System`は省略可能です。そのため、`Net.WebClient`は`System.Net.WebClient`として扱われます。

なお、PowerShellにおいてファイルのダウンロードは[`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)が利用でき

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://<IP>:<Port>/<File Name>' -OutFile 'C:\<Path>\to\<File Name>'
```

と書けます。